# Add settings to plugins cp section instead of settings page

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I've setup a plugin like so `http://domain/admin/plugin-handle` (cp section) and a settings page here `http://domain/admin/settings/plugins/plugin-handle`

I can edit my plugin settings under the latter URL, however I would like non admins to be able to do so as well, but under `http://domain/admin/plugin-handle`

How can I go about this? Adding e.g.

```
{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Headline'|t('craft-terms-of-service'),
    instructions: 'Enter the headline of your TOS here.'|t('craft-terms-of-service'),
    id: 'tosHeadline',
    name: 'tosHeadline',
    value: settings['tosHeadline']})
}}
```

to the `http://domain/admin/plugin-handle` template (`src/templates/index.twig`) (cp section) non-admins have access to, I get `Variable "settings" does not exist.` I can't figure out how to make it accessible/exist.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Figured out how to add fields to the cp section through the "Getting Started with Craft Plugin Development" course on craftquest.io, however the way I'm saving the settings to the db is rather crude. I'm just doing `Craft::$app->db->createCommand(....` to update the `plugins` table. It works, but I'm sure there are much more elegant ways of doing it?

Comment: Glad you figured it out, Stian... would you mind adding your solution to the original question as an answer, then post your new settings saving question as a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

In my `src/template/index` file I added this to make the form work

```
{% extends "_layouts/cp" %}
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

<form action="" method="post">
{{ csrfInput() }}

{{ forms.hidden({
    name: 'action',
    value: 'craft-terms-of-service/default/save-tos'
}) }}

{{ forms.hidden({
    name: 'tosCurrentVersion',
    value: now.timestamp
}) }}

{{ forms.lightswitchField({
    label: 'Enable TOS?'|t,
    id: 'tosEnabled',
    name: 'tosEnabled',
    on: craft.craftTermsOfService.get('tosEnabled'),
    first: true
}) }}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: 'Headline'|t('craft-terms-of-service'),
    instructions: 'Enter the headline of your TOS here.'|t('craft-terms-of-service'),
    id: 'tosHeadline',
    name: 'tosHeadline',
    value: craft.craftTermsOfService.get('tosHeadline')
}) }}

{{ craft.craftTermsOfService.redactorField({
    label: 'Terms of Service'|t('craft-terms-of-service'),
    instructions: 'Enter the TOS every user must accept before using the site below.'|t('craft-terms-of-service'),
    name: 'tosBody',
    rows: 4,
    value: craft.craftTermsOfService.get('tosBody')|raw
})|raw }}

<input type="submit" class="submit btn" value="{{ 'Save'|t }}">
```

Using the `actions/craft-terms-of-service/default/save-tos` controller I took the data from the request and updated the data in the `plugins` table. Also in the form in my `index` template I used the `craft.craftTermsOfService.get` variable to fetch the settings from the `plugins` table and give each form element its appropriate value.

For details, see the [controller on github](https://github.com/stianmandarin/crafttermsofservice/blob/master/src/controllers/DefaultController.php) and the [variable](https://github.com/stianmandarin/crafttermsofservice/blob/master/src/variables/CraftTermsOfServiceVariable.php) on github. Note this is the first time I make a plugin, so it's probably a mess, sorry about that.